# Кнопка поделиться по email в виджете "Блок «Поделиться»" от Яндекс

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Мне кажется нехватает информации в разделе "поделиться" пункты отправить на email(другу\себе). Как это сделать? возможно ли отправить не открывая почту, а просто написать адрес ящика и туда улетит письмо со ссылкой или само страницей?

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно [вот вопрос 2017 года](https://yandex.ru/blog/share/dobavit-knopku-otpravki-email), придется реализовать самому или использовать другие виджеты [типа addThis](http://www.addthis.com/get/share/).

Comment: mailto:? (7 символов)

Comment: да, конечно, но письмо "не улетит".